# Mongodb c# library Async

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using ASP.net Web API and MongoDB to create a simple service.

I am using the official Mongodb C# library.

How can I make it Async? I think the official Mongodb C# library does not support Async.

Can I just make the controller Async but not the select statement?

Controller:

```
 public IQueryable<Test> GetAllPlaces()
 {
     return _test.GetAllPlaces().AsQueryable();
 }
```

Select from mongodb database:

```
public IEnumerable<Test> GetAllPlaces()
{
     return _test.FindAll();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: The latest 2.0 release fully supports async operation, take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you could make it async, doing so won't provide you any real performance gains as the underlying library isn't Async. There's a lot more to it and is described well [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx). The general answer is "no."

Answer (score 4):

Bit old question, but a full async MongoDB driver for C# is coming up in Nov 2013:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-138

edit- As Eugene said, the driver is still under development. There are some experimental projects on Github, while we wait for the official one

https://github.com/rstam/mongo-async-csharp-driver
https://github.com/andrebires/mongo-csharp-driver

**02-Apr-2015 Update:**

2.0 is out!: [Nuget Link](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver/)
But be aware that async GridFS is not supported yet, you'll need to keep using the [legacy package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/mongocsharpdriver/) to work with it, until they release it, probably in [version 2.1](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1191)

(thanks paqogomez for the heads up)

Comment: the updated timeline for the async support is **Q1 2014**:

from Craig Wilson comment:
...we don't have an ETA yet, but it will likely be Q1 of 2014. In addition, async will only be supported for .NET 4.5.

Comment: [2.0 is now out](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.0/html/R_Project_CSharpDriverDocs.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Hopping on an old thread here, but FYI in C# you can let your queries run with `SafeMode.False` as a parameter, (i beleive it's actually off by default) which will execute them in fire and forget manner.

My code for most of my stuff looks like this:

```
IMongoQuery query = Query.EQ("_id", Path);
IMongoUpdate update = Update.Set("Key", "value"); 
SafeModeResult oCmd = mCollection.Update(query, update, SafeMode.True);
```

Because i need safe mode. But if you set it to false or leave that paramter out, you'll get the fire and forget functionality.